# How can I display two div(class) in one line via css inline property

Tags: html, css, class, date

How do I make so that date/time locates next to username?

```
<li class="comment">
   <div class="username">sundar</div><!-- element 1-->
   <span class="createdAt">2019-01-03 12:30:20</span>
   <div class="content">code now! #work #hard</div><br>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey thats just easy to make with Flexbox.

If you want to learn more about this CSS Property: [MDN Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) or [CSS Tricks Flexbox Sheet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Here is an example fiddle:

```css
.comment{

  /* flex-styles */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  /* additional | not needed */
  
  background: black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.comment .column{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* additional | not needed */
.comment span{ color: white; }
```

```html
<li class="comment">
  <div class="column">
    <span class="username">sundar</span>
    <span class="content">code now! #work #hard</span>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <span class="createdAt">2019-01-03 12:30:20</span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Because the Author of this Questions has send an example which shows this two line not just next to each other, but also with quite space. 

Flexbox is the Industry-standard. 
'display: inline-block' simply is not enough here.

Comment: of course it is, see my sample, you dont ened to change the HTML code at all. I know that flex boxes with CSS-Grid is the standard. But using alternative methods > changing HTML structure

Comment: Dude, I don’t want to be harsh. No one in 2020 uses „float“ anymore. It‘s outdated and caused bugs in several states of grid management. Float will be a deprecated feature in the future.

Answer (score 0):

change the div `.username` to an inline-block with `.username { display: inline-block; }` . You can use float then to push the date to the right side. Flexboxes might be a modern way, but would require a change in HTML structure.

```css
.username {
  display: inline-block;
}

.createdAt {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<li class="comment">
      <div class="username">sundar</div><!-- element 1-->
      <span class="createdAt">2019-01-03 12:30:20</span>
      <div class="content">code now! #work #hard</div><br>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flex box

```
<li class="comment">
  <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;justify-content:space-between">
    <div class="username" style="float:left">sundar</div><!-- element 1-->
    <span class="createdAt">2019-01-03 12:30:20</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">code now! #work #hard</div><br>
</li>
```

here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbmgw605/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a div around the elements that you want to have on the same line as a wrapper.
Than use Flexbox to space the contents over the entire width.

Also, you can use the HTML style attribute to include CSS in your HTML, or you can use a separate CSS file for your styling.

```html
<div class="comment" style="width:300px; background: #CFEBF7; padding:20px; font-family:sans-serif;">
  <div class='wrapper' style="display:flex; justify-content: space-between;">
      <span class="username"><strong>Sundar</strong></span>
      <span class="createdAt">2019-01-03 12:30:20</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">code now! #work #hard</div><br>
</div>
```

Edit: changed background color, font and added padding to reflect example more precisely.